# Python generics and subclasses

Tags: python, generics, mypy

I'm trying to add type annotations to an existing package, and clearly I'm missing something important. I have an abstract superclass, and subclasses. The superclass should be generic, whereas the subclasses should be for a specific type. Here's a simple example if that I see, and what I'd like to see:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class A(Generic[T]):
    def method(self, arg: T):
        ...

class B(A[int]):
    def method(self, arg):
        reveal_locals()
```

Expected (or at least hoped for):

```
GenericTest.py:11: note: Revealed local types are:
GenericTest.py:11: note:     arg: int
GenericTest.py:11: note:     self: Any
```

Got:

```
GenericTest.py:11: note: Revealed local types are:
GenericTest.py:11: note:     arg: Any
GenericTest.py:11: note:     self: Any
```

Comment: This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3903) and it does not seem there are plans to implement it

Answer (score 7):

You need to add type annotations to the methods in your subclass. So doing:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class A(Generic[T]):
    def method(self, arg: T) -> None:
        ...

class B(A[int]):
    def method(self, arg: int) -> None:
        reveal_locals()
```

...results in the expected output of:

```
test.py:11: note: Revealed local types are:
test.py:11: note:     arg: builtins.int
test.py:11: note:     self: test.B
```

If a function is not annotated with type hints, mypy will [treat that function as being dynamically typed](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#function-signatures-and-dynamic-vs-static-typing) and assume all of its arguments are of type `Any`.

If you would like mypy to warn you when you forget type hints like this, run mypy with the [`--disallow-untyped-defs` command line flag](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#untyped-definitions-and-calls) -- and also maybe `--disallow-incomplete-defs` for good measure. Or alternatively, run mypy with the `--strict` flag, which automatically enables the above two flags (and more).

Comment: That certainly works, but feels repetitive - I need `int` in two places (and perhaps more in real world cases). Class `A` is defined over a generic type `T`, and I was hoping to be able to define a subclass setting `T` to a concrete type, just the once, but I see that isn't going to work.

Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 6):

`reveal_locals()` prints the types of the variables inferred by mypy in the scope where the call its placed. And when redefining a method in a subclass, you are also overriding the annotations (`Any` is used by default when no parameter annotation is given explicitly)

This could be more clear:

```py
class A(Generic[T]):
    def method(self, arg: T):
        ...

class B(A[int]):
    def method(self, arg):
        pass

B().method('')
```

The above code is fine for mypy but the next gives an error:

```py
class C(A[int]):
    pass

C().method('')
```

```sh
error: Argument 1 to "method" of "A" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

Comment: I my case, I do need to override the method in the subclass, and I was hoping to specify the subclasses concrete type just the once. Looks like I can't do that. Thanks for your help, though!